# Search/get original function/method location in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Assuming I have this code

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\Something\Class1;
use App\Something\Class2;
use App\Something\Class3;

trait Helpers {

    public function someThingCool( $someVar) {

        return $this->checkCoolness( $someVar );

    }
}
```

is there some way I can easily determine and locate where that `checkCoolness` method originally define without going through each of inherited class?

Answer (score 0):

### Use `Go to Definition` in the context menu

Right click on a desired function and click on `go to definition`

[image]

---

#### Setting shortcut.

Press `ctrl+shift+p` and type in `keyboard-shortcuts`

Type in `go to definition` in the search bar

Set desired keybinding to `Go to Definition`. Say `ctrl + B`

Now use your keybinding (*shortcut*) to access the definition of `checkCoolness` click on `checkCoolness` and press `ctrl + B`

[image]